# How can observations of random variables be IID, if they are not themselves random variables?

Tags: random-variable, terminology, independence

Suppose we perform some experiment which results in an outcome $\omega \in \Omega$. A random variable $X$ maps $\omega$ to a real number, and the (discrete) distribution $P(X)$ maps $X$ to $[0, 1]$. Now, suppose we perform $N$ such experiments, so that we have $N$ observations of $X$, $\{X^{(1)}, \dotsc, X^{(N)}\}$. Each observation $X^{(n)}$ is thus a real number.

Based on the above, I'm confused when several of my textbooks refer to observations being IID, since IID is a property of a collection of random variables, not values.

Additionally, consider this equation, which is used to show that the sample mean $\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}X^{(n)}$ is an unbiased estimator of the mean $\mu$ of $P(X)$.

$\begin{equation*}
E(\hat{\mu}) = E\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}X^{(n)}\right) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N} E(X^{(n)}) = \mu.
\end{equation*}$

This equation implies $E(X^{(n)}) = E(X)$. Based on my understanding that $X^{(n)}$ is a real number, I would expect $E(X^{(n)}) = X^{(n)}$.

Comment: Would it help to point out that sometimes you use notation like "$X^{(i)}$" to refer to *functions* (random variables) and other times you use the same notation to refer to the *values* of those functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *model* is that the random variables $X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n$ are iid (independent identically distributed). That is a property of the *model*, not of the data.

Your *data* is then $x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_n$, where each $x_i$ is a realized value of the model random variable $X_i$. Colloquially, informally one may say that $x_1, x_2, \dotsc,x_n$ are iid, but that is just a shorthand for the longer statements above.

**EDIT** Trying to clarify, questions in comments:

> And what do you mean by model here as there's no mention of model in
> the question?

A model here is a (mathematical) representation of reality (part of), specifically, the modeling here consists in representing the observations as random variables (functions), usually written by uppercase $X$ while its *realized values* is represented by $x$. Part of the OP's problem is that he does not distinguish clearly between the two.

Comment: I also stumbled on this question. Can you please be a little elaborate perhaps with an example? And what do you mean by model here as there's no mention of model in the question?

Comment: That there is no mention of *model* in the question is maybe part of what confuses the OP, since he is mixing up the random variables (which here is the *model*) with its realized values.

Comment: Do you taking "model" in the sense that ML models are taken or in the sense when we model (assert relation) a quantity?

Comment: Can you answer my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993356/understanding-the-difference-between-different-iid-random-variables-and-diffe
I've tried to explain it in the comments.